# difference of format and round mysql

Tags: mysql, format, rounding

i would like to know if there is a difference between **round**((first + second + third + fourth)/4,2) and **format**((first + second + third + fourth)/4,2),

i tried it in my database but I didnt see a difference, i'm working on a project that needs to be precise

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rounds the argument X to D decimal places. The rounding algorithm depends on the data 
type of X. D defaults to 0 if not specified. D can be negative to cause D digits left of 
the decimal point of the value X to become zero.

```
-->ROUND(X,D)
```

Formats the number X to a format like '#,###,###.##', rounded to D decimal places, and returns the result as a string. If D is 0, the result has no decimal point or fractional part. D should be a constant value.

```
--> FORMAT(X,D)
```

Comment: it's been a while.. i just saw your post, thanks  :)

Comment: @makoto much more explanation is needed to be done. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The ROUND() function in MySQL is used to round a FLOAT number to a specified number of decimal places.

**Syntax :**

`ROUND(X, D);`

- **X** : The number which we want to round.
- **D** : Number of decimal places up to which we want to round the number. It is optional. It can be zero, +ve, -ve or absent.

**Case 1:** D is absent -

The FLOAT number is rounded to INT number. If digit to the right of decimal point >= 5, one is added to the INT number, else the INT number is kept as it is.

```
SELECT ROUND(45.4);
+-------------+
| ROUND(45.4) |
+-------------+
|          45 |
+-------------+
```

```
SELECT ROUND(45.5);
+-------------+
| ROUND(45.5) |
+-------------+
|          46 |
+-------------+
```

```
SELECT ROUND(45.6);
+-------------+
| ROUND(45.6) |
+-------------+
|          46 |
+-------------+
```

**Case 2:** D is zero -

Same result as Case 1

```
SELECT ROUND(45.4, 0);
+----------------+
| ROUND(45.4, 0) |
+----------------+
|             45 |
+----------------+
```

```
SELECT ROUND(45.5, 0);
+----------------+
| ROUND(45.5, 0) |
+----------------+
|             46 |
+----------------+
```

```
SELECT ROUND(45.6, 0);
+----------------+
| ROUND(45.6, 0) |
+----------------+
|             46 |
+----------------+
```

**Case 3:** D is positive -

The FLOAT number is rounded up to 'D' number of digits to the right of decimal point. If the digit at 'D+1' <= 4, digit at 'D' is kept same. If the digit at 'D+1' >= 5, digit at 'D' is increased by 1.

```
SELECT ROUND(45.44, 1);
+-----------------+
| ROUND(45.44, 1) |
+-----------------+
|            45.4 |
+-----------------+
```

```
SELECT ROUND(45.45, 1);
+-----------------+
| ROUND(45.45, 1) |
+-----------------+
|            45.5 |
+-----------------+
```

```
SELECT ROUND(45.46, 1);
+-----------------+
| ROUND(45.46, 1) |
+-----------------+
|            45.5 |
+-----------------+
```

**Case 4:** D is negative -

The FLOAT number is rounded up to 'D' number of digits to the left of decimal point. If the digit at 'D' <= 4, digit at 'D-1' is kept same. If the digit at 'D' >= 5, digit at 'D-1' is increased by 1.

```
SELECT ROUND(44.4, -1);
+-----------------+
| ROUND(44.4, -1) |
+-----------------+
|              40 |
+-----------------+
```

```
SELECT ROUND(45.4, -1);
+-----------------+
| ROUND(45.4, -1) |
+-----------------+
|              50 |
```

```
SELECT ROUND(46.4, -1);
+-----------------+
| ROUND(46.4, -1) |
+-----------------+
|              50 |
+-----------------+
```

---

---

The FORMAT() function in MySQL is used to format the number in a format of "#, ###. ##", rounded to certain decimal places. After formatting the number, it will return the value as a **string**.

**Syntax :**

`FORMAT(N, D, locale);`

- **N:** The number that we want to format.
- **D:** Number of decimal places up to which we want to round the number. It can be zero, or +ve.
- **locale:** The locale is an optional argument that determines the thousand separators and grouping between separators. By default, MySQL will use an 'en_US' locale.

For the parameter **D**, important differences between ROUND() and FORMAT() functions -

- Unlike ROUND() function, in FORMAT() function D is **not optional**
- Unlike ROUND() function, in FORMAT() function a negative value of D has the same effect as zero value.
- Unlike ROUND() function, in FORMAT() function when value of D is greater than the number of digits after decimal place  - zeroes are added to the right of the last digit

Rest of the rules are same in the two functions

When D is greater than the number of digits after decimal place -

```
SELECT FORMAT(23435.37, 3);
+---------------------+
| FORMAT(23435.37, 3) |
+---------------------+
| 23,435.370          |
+---------------------+
```

```
SELECT FORMAT(23435.37, 4);
+---------------------+
| FORMAT(23435.37, 4) |
+---------------------+
| 23,435.3700         |
+---------------------+
```

When D is zero -

```
SELECT FORMAT(23435.37, 0);
+---------------------+
| FORMAT(23435.37, 0) |
+---------------------+
| 23,435              |
+---------------------+
```

When D is negative -

```
SELECT FORMAT(23435.37, -1);
+----------------------+
| FORMAT(23435.37, -1) |
+----------------------+
| 23,435               |
+----------------------+
```

When D is positive -

```
SELECT FORMAT(23435.34, 1);
+---------------------+
| FORMAT(23435.34, 1) |
+---------------------+
| 23,435.3            |
+---------------------+
```

```
SELECT FORMAT(23435.35, 1);
+---------------------+
| FORMAT(23435.35, 1) |
+---------------------+
| 23,435.4            |
+---------------------+
```

```
SELECT FORMAT(23435.36, 1);
+---------------------+
| FORMAT(23435.36, 1) |
+---------------------+
| 23,435.4            |
+---------------------+
```

The **locale** parameter is optional. Omitting it makes the format 'en_US' by default.

```
SELECT FORMAT(2894581234.389, 2);
+---------------------------+
| FORMAT(2894581234.389, 2) |
+---------------------------+
| 2,894,581,234.39          |
+---------------------------+
```

**locale** parameter can also be explicitly stated as 'en_US'

```
SELECT FORMAT(2894581234.389, 2, 'en_US');
+------------------------------------+
| FORMAT(2894581234.389, 2, 'en_US') |
+------------------------------------+
| 2,894,581,234.39                   |
+------------------------------------+
```

Here, the **locale** parameter is being changed to 'en_IN'. There is a change in format

```
SELECT FORMAT(2894581234.389, 2, 'en_IN');
+------------------------------------+
| FORMAT(2894581234.389, 2, 'en_IN') |
+------------------------------------+
| 2,89,45,81,234.39                  |
+------------------------------------+
```

Here, the **locale** parameter is changed to 'de_DE'. Again there is change in format.

```
SELECT FORMAT(2894581234.389, 2, 'de_DE');
+------------------------------------+
| FORMAT(2894581234.389, 2, 'de_DE') |
+------------------------------------+
| 2.894.581.234,39                   |
+------------------------------------+
```